# Delphi: better design to avoid circular unit reference?

Tags: delphi, circular-reference

I have a triangular mesh structure in Delphi 10.

For performance reasons I store the data of the mesh's vertices, triangle faces, etc. in descendants of TList.

I let the TLists do the calculations for every member of the list. For these calculations I need access to some fields of the TMesh structure. Therefore during the creation of TMesh and subsequently the creation of the lists I assign the parent TMesh to the lists. I use a forward declaration of TMesh to do so. Please see the following code:

```
type
  {forward declaration}
  TMesh=class;

  TVertex=record
    Point: TPoint3D;
    //other fields
  end;

  TVertices=class(TList<TVertex>)
    Mesh: TMesh;
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllVertices; //uses some fields of TMesh
    constructor Create(const AMesh: TMesh);
    //other methods
  end;

  TTriangleFace=record
    Vertices: Array[0..2] of Integer;
    //other fields
  end;

  TTriangleFaces=class(TList<TTriangleFace>)
    Mesh: TMesh;
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces; //uses some fields of TMesh
    constructor Create(const AMesh: TMesh);
    //other methods
  end;

  TMesh=class(TComponent)
    Vertices: TVertices;
    TriangleFaces: TTriangleFaces;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    //other fields & methods
  end;

implementation

constructor TMesh.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Vertices:=TVertices.Create(Self);
  TriangleFaces:=TTriangleFaces.Create(Self);
end;

constructor TVertices.Create(const AMesh: TMesh);
begin
  Mesh:=AMesh;
end;
```

This works fine.

However since my project is growing I am getting more and more code and I want to distribute the list classes in separate units. This results in the problem of circular unit references.

The problem of circular unit references seems quite well known. I checked for possible solutions but I cannot find one which seem to fit my problem. Some say that if you run into circular unit references the code is poorly designed.

How can I improve the design and at the same time keep the calculation performance high?

What are other possibilities to solve the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not have `TVertices` execute a callback instead of needing to access the mesh directly?  That way `TMesh` can inject the method and you get around `TVertices` needing to know about the class that is containing it.  As for the circular reference problem, it's nearly impossible to suggest a solution without seeing your code.  Extracting shared types into separates units is one common way to do this, but it's hard to be more specific without code to work with.

Comment: @J... Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please give an example how such a callback and injection of the method would look like?

Comment: This is as close as I could dig up from memory - the context is a little different and it works in a threaded context but the general idea of implementing a callback is there if it's a novel concept to you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19298903/327083

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current solution is already the best way to solve the problem. Splitting these types into separate units creates significant obstacles and will lead to unwieldy code.

Whilst I can understand your desire to split these types apart, you have to balance that desire against the clarity of the resulting code. In this case the negative consequences of splitting far out weigh the positives. Leave the code as it is.

Answer (score 9):

Forward declarations do not work across units.  When a unit forward declares a record/class, the same unit must also define the record/class.

I would suggest defining an `IMesh` interface that `TMesh` implements, and then have `TVertices` and `TTriangleFaces` use `IMesh` instead of `TMesh` directly.  That way, there is no circular reference, and the interface can expose properties for whatever field values are needed.  And `TComponent` disables reference counting for implemented interfaces, so memory leaking is not an issue.

MeshIntf.pas:

```
unit MeshIntf;

interface

type
  IMesh = interface(IInterface)
    ['{30315BC6-9A2E-4430-96BB-297D11C9DB5D}']
    // methods for performing common tasks...
    // properties for reading/setting needed values...
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Vertices.pas:

```
unit Vertices;

interface

uses
  System.Types, System.Generics.Collections, MeshIntf;

type
  TVertex = record
    Point: TPoint3D;
    //other fields
  end;

  TVertices = class(TList<TVertex>)
  public
    Mesh: IMesh;
    constructor Create(const AMesh: IMesh); reintroduce;
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllVertices;
    //other methods
  end;

implementation

constructor TVertices.Create(const AMesh: IMesh);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Mesh := AMesh;
end;

procedure TVertices.DoSomethingWithAllVertices;
begin
  // use properties/methods of Mesh as needed...
end;

end.
```

TriangleFaces.pas:

```
unit TriangleFaces;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, MeshIntf;

type
  TTriangleFace = record
    Vertices: Array[0..2] of Integer;
    //other fields
  end;

  TTriangleFaces = class(TList<TTriangleFace>)
  public
    Mesh: IMesh;
    constructor Create(const AMesh: IMesh); reintroduce;
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces;
    //other methods
  end;

implementation

constructor TTriangleFaces.Create(const AMesh: IMesh);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Mesh := AMesh;
end;

procedure TTriangleFaces.DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces;
begin
  // use properties/methods of Mesh as needed...
end;

end.
```

Mesh.pas:

```
unit Mesh;

interface

uses
  Classes, MeshIntf, Vertices, TriangleFaces;

type
  TMesh = class(TComponent, IMesh)
  public
    Vertices: TVertices;
    TriangleFaces: TTriangleFaces;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    //other fields & methods, and IMesh implementation
  end;

implementation

constructor TMesh.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Vertices := TVertices.Create(Self as IMesh);
  TriangleFaces := TTriangleFaces.Create(Self as IMesh);
end;

destructor TMesh.Destroy;
begin
  Vertices.Free;
  TriangleFaces.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

If you don't need `TMesh` to be available at design-time to the Form Designer and Object Inspector, you should derive it from `TInterfacedObject` instead of `TComponent`.  But then you need to make some small tweaks to handle reference counting correctly (which `TComponent` disables).  In particular, `TVertices` and `TTriangleFaces` need to use *weak referencing* so as not to increment the `TMesh`'s reference count and cause a memory leak (since its reference count will ever fall to 0 in that scenario):

MeshIntf.pas:

```
unit MeshIntf;

interface

uses
  System.Types;

type
  TVertex = record
    Point: TPoint3D;
    //other fields
  end;

  IVertices = interface(IInterface)
    ['{97A70A11-C8B6-4DBC-807B-B9E0C6953B9E}']
    // methods for performing tasks...
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllVertices;
    function GetVertex(Index: Integer): TVertex;
    // properties for reading/setting values...
    property Vertex[Index: Integer]: TVertex read GetVertex;
  end;

  TTriangleFace = record
    Vertices: Array[0..2] of Integer;
    //other fields
  end;

  ITriangleFaces = interface(IInterface)
    ['{A1ED479B-7430-4524-A630-FDDE212375BB}']
    // methods for performing tasks...
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces;
    function GetFace(Index: Integer): TTriangleFace;
    // properties for reading/setting values...
    property Face[Index: Integer]: TTriangleFace read GetFace;
  end;

  IMesh = interface(IInterface)
    ['{30315BC6-9A2E-4430-96BB-297D11C9DB5D}']
    // methods for performing common tasks...
    function GetVertices: IVertices;
    function GetTriangleFaces: ITriangleFaces;
    // properties for reading/setting values...
    property Vertices: IVertices read GetVertices;
    property TriangleFaces: ITriangleFaces read GetTriangleFaces;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Vertices.pas:

```
unit Vertices;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, MeshIntf;

type
  TVertices = class(TInterfacedObject, IVertices)
  private
    // Delphi 10.1 Berlin adds [weak] support to all compilers,
    // it was previously only available on the mobile compilers...
    {$IFDEF WEAKINTFREF}
    [weak] fMesh: IMesh;
    {$ELSE}
    fMesh: Pointer;
    {$ENDIF}

    fVertices: TList<TVertex>;

  public
    constructor Create(AMesh: IMesh);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    //other methods

    // IVertices implementation
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllVertices;
    function GetVertex(Index: Integer): TVertex;
  end;

implementation

constructor TVertices.Create(AMesh: IMesh);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fMesh := {$IFDEF WEAKINTFREF}AMesh{$ELSE}Pointer(AMesh){$ENDIF};
  fVertices := TList<TVertex>.Create;
end;

destructor TVertices.Destroy;
begin
  fVertices.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TVertices.DoSomethingWithAllVertices;
begin
  // use properties of fMesh as needed...

  // if WEAKINTFREF is not defined simply type-cast the Mesh
  // pointer as IMesh(fMesh) when accessing its members...
end;

function TVertices.GetVertex(Index: Integer): TVertex;
begin
  Result := fVertices[Index];
end;

end.
```

TriangleFaces.pas:

```
unit TriangleFaces;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, MeshIntf;

type
  TTriangleFaces = class(TInterfacedObject, ITriangleFaces)
  private
    // Delphi 10.1 Berlin adds [weak] support to all compilers,
    // it was previously only available on the mobile compilers...
    {$IFDEF WEAKINTFREF}
    [weak] fMesh: IMesh;
    {$ELSE}
    fMesh: Pointer;
    {$ENDIF}

    fFaces: TList<TTriangleFace>;

  public
    constructor Create(AMesh: IMesh);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    //other methods

    // ITriangleFaces implementation
    procedure DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces;
    function GetFace(Index: Integer): TTriangleFace;
  end;

implementation

constructor TTriangleFaces.Create(AMesh: IMesh);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fMesh := {$IFDEF WEAKINTFREF}AMesh{$ELSE}Pointer(AMesh){$ENDIF};
  fFaces := TList<TTriangleFace>.Create;
end;

destructor TTriangleFaces.Destroy;
begin
  fFaces.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTriangleFaces.DoSomethingWithAllTriangleFaces;
begin
  // use properties of fMesh as needed...

  // if WEAKINTFREF is not defined simply type-cast the Mesh
  // pointer as IMesh(fMesh) when accessing its members...
end;

function TTriangleFaces.GetFace(Index: Integer): TTriangleFace;
begin
  Result := fFaces[Index];
end;

end.
```

Mesh.pas:

```
unit Mesh;

interface

uses
  MeshIntf;

type
  TMesh = class(TInterfacedObject, IMesh)
  private
    // note, these are *strong* references, not*weak* references!
    fVertices: IVertices;
    fTriangleFaces: ITriangleFaces;

  public
    constructor Create;

    //other fields & methods

    // IMesh implementation
    function GetVertices: IVertices;
    function GetTriangleFaces: ITriangleFaces;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Vertices, TriangleFaces;

constructor TMesh.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fVertices := TVertices.Create(Self as IMesh);
  fTriangleFaces := TTriangleFaces.Create(Self as IMesh);
end;

function TMesh.GetVertices: IVertices;
begin
  Result := fVertices;
end;

function TMesh.GetTriangleFaces: ITriangleFaces;
begin
  Result := fTriangleFaces;
end;

end.
```

Just be sure you have a non-weak `IMesh` variable somewhere in your code when creating the `TMesh` object so it stays alive until you do not need it anymore:

```
var
  Meth: IMesh; // or a class member or a global, wherever you need it

Mesh := TMesh.Create;
...
Mesh := nil;
```

(Proper) reference counting will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: `TMesh` inherits from `TComponent` and `TComponent` has disabled reference counting. Now you've got an interface `IMesh` that will not clean up after itself.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine.  When the `TMesh` is freed, the `TVertices`/`TTriangleFaces` will be freed.  The lifetime of the `TMesh` does not depend on the lifetimes of the `TVertices`/`TTriangleFaces`, it is the other way around. The `Owner` of the `TMesh` will free it automatically when the `Owner` is freed. If the `Owner` is nil, the code that creates the `TMesh` is responsible for freeing it manually.  There is no leak issue here.  Reference counting is only important if the `TMesh` needs to be freed automatically when all `IMesh` instances are released, and that is not the case here.

Comment: `TComponent` itself implements several interfaces, and it is not uncommon for component authors to implement custom interfaces on their components.  It works just fine.

Comment: OK, That makes sense. You should explain the caveat in the answer though. The OP might use `IMesh` in another context and expect ARC semantics.

Comment: If the OP wants ARC semantics on `TMesh`, then either derive it from `TInterfacedObject` instead of `TComponent` (`TComponent` is only needed if `TMesh` should be usable at design-time), or else re-enable reference counting by overriding the `_AddRef` and `_Release` methods (which `TComponent` has implemented to disable reference counting).

Comment: @Remy, thank you for the detailed answer. I do not need `TMesh` at design time. Should I use `TInterfacedObject` then?

Comment: @user3384674: If you go the `interface` route without `TComponent`, then yes, unless you implement the `QueryInterface()`, `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` methods yourself (`TInterfacedObject` implements them for you). If `TMesh` is reference counted, then `TVertices`/`TTriangleFaces` need to use *weak referencing* to avoid incrementing the reference count causing `TMesh` to be leaked (circular *strong reference* issue). Whoever creates the `TMesh` object will need an `IMesh` variable to keep it alive until not needed anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What about the performance when using with `IMesh` and `TInterfacedObject`? E.g. when in `TVertices.DoSomethingWithAllVertices` in a loop I use something like `AValue:=Mesh.TriangleFaces[i].Vertices[j];`? Is this slower than the current code without the use of interfaces?

Comment: @user3384674: Not noticeably, no (just the overhead of virtual method calls). However, if you allow *direct access* to `TVertices`/`TTriangleFaces` objects from `IMesh`, you create new unit circular references (`MeshIntf` will need to reference `Vertices`/`TriangleFaces`, which reference `MeshIntf` - now you are back to square-one!). `MeshIntf` could define extra interfaces for `TVertices`/`TTriangleFaces` to implement, and then `IMesh` can use those interfaces as needed. Using interfaces like this decouples the units from each other.

Comment: Yes it will be slower. The memory layout is much less amenable caching.

Comment: For performance reasons I finally decided to leave the code in one unit as David Heffernan suggests. The answer from Remy Lebeau is very detailed and shows a good example for using interfaces. I will keep this in mind for other parts of the project which are less performance critical.